# How to visualize two distributions

Tags: python, plot, scipy, statistics, distribution

I am doing MCMC, and I have two distributions:

```
from scipy.stats import lognorm
from scipy.stats import uniform
import numpy as np
prior_fb = uniform(loc=0, scale=0.1)
post_fb = lognorm(s=np.log(1.15), scale=0.0076)
```

How do I compare the prior and posterior distributions in the same plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from scipy.stats import lognorm
from scipy.stats import uniform
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

prior_fb = uniform(loc=0, scale=0.1)
post_fb = lognorm(s=np.log(1.15), scale=0.0076)

x = np.linspace(0, 0.1, 1000)
plt.plot(x, prior_fb.pdf(x), x, post_fb.pdf(x));
plt.legend(['prior', 'post'])
```